How to save image as a useable icon without Online converters
I have been searching online for a while now on how to make my own icon without an online converter and they ALL say the same thing and they all do not work. Namely change the pixel count to 16x16 / 32x32 / 256x256, save as bmp/png/jpg and then rename the file to .ico.
However this does not work because it is not in the proper icon format. Visual Studio gives the error when trying to use such a homemade icon.
Error building Win32 resources -- Icon stream is not in the expected format

What does work however is using online ico conversion tools. But why does one need to do that? What voodoo magic do these online tools do that I cannot using paint or whatever to make an icon file?

A Windows icon file is not just a bitmap. One .ico file can contain multiple images in different resolutions or color depth. Some operating systems are less restrictive for desktop images, but Microsoft has defined a standard that is not the same as JPEG, TIFF, PNG or other image format. Each .ico file starts with an, "ICONDIR ("Icon directory") structure, containing an ICONDIRENTRY [sub]structure for each image in the file, followed by a contiguous block of all image bitmap data."
There is free and commercial software to edit icons, such as greenfish icon editor and alternatives. Most of these tools can also make cursor files, .cur and .ani, which are similar to .ico standards, but set one pixel as hotspot, and the .ani format includes animation.

Thank you, I wish all the online tutuorials and instructions at least had such a disclaimer instead of "just save it in this pixel resolution with paint!"
